# Hibernate - @ManyToOne annotation creates additional column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So I am following a tutorial about hibernate as i want to use the framework in an upcoming project. I'm having a problem with the @ManyToOne and @OneToMay annotation and Bidirectional mapping. What i want to do is very basic stuff. I simply want two tables, one reperesenting a user, and the other one representing a vehicle. Now i want the user to be able to have many vehicles and a car should "know" the user it belongs to.

As it seems to be "best practice" to create an extra table that holds the connection between users and and vehicles. I tried to do this with the @JoinTable annotation(see below) but it is not working as i want it to.

To do this, I have coded the following classes:

**UserDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int userId;
private String userName;
private String email;
@OneToMany()
@JoinTable(name="USER_VEHICLE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID")
)
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicle = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

...
getters and setters
```

**vehicle.java**

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int vehicleId;
private String vehicleName;
@ManyToOne  
private UserDetails user;

...
getters and setters
```

And class to test the above:

**HibernateTest.Java**

```
public class HibernateTest {
/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args){

    UserDetails user1 = new UserDetails();      
    user1.setUserName("testUser1");
    user1.setEmail("testEmail1");


    Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle();
    vehicle1.setVehicleName("Car");

    Vehicle vehicle2 = new Vehicle();
    vehicle2.setVehicleName("Jeep");

    user1.getVehicle().add(vehicle1);
    user1.getVehicle().add(vehicle2);
    vehicle1.setUser(user1);
    vehicle2.setUser(user1);    

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user1);
    session.save(vehicle1);
    session.save(vehicle2);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

When I run this, it executes without any errors or exceptions and it creates the following tables:

```
USER_DETAILS
+------+----------+---------+
|userId|email     |userName |
+------+----------+---------+
|1     |testEmail1|testUser1|
+------+----------+---------+

VEHICLE
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|vehicleId|vehicleName|user_userId| <- did not expect this column
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|1        |Car        |1          |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
|2        |Jeep       |1          |
+---------+-----------+-----------+

USER_VEHICLE
 +------+----------+
|USER_ID|VEHICLE_ID|
+-------+----------+
|1      |1         |
+-------+----------+
|1      |2         |
+-------+----------+
```

As I understand it, the additional column "user_userId" that was created by hibernate seems to be unnecessary, as the connection between users and vehicles is already represented in the "USER_VEHICLE" table, and I did not intend to have this additional column created.

Is the way I did the bidirectional mapping wrong? And what is the right way to get this to work without the additional column being created?

Comment: That join table is unnecessary in one to many relationships.  Those are only necessary in many to many relationships.  Since the vehicle is only assigned to one user the foriegn key from the user table goes into the vehicle table (the extra column you see).  The join table is only necessary  when a user can have multiple vehicles AND vehicles can have multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@JoinTable` is necessary if you want a `@ManyToMany` relationship.

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_vehicle",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id"))
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}

@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    /* ... */
}
```

```
USER_DETAILS      VEHICLE           USER_VEHICLE
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+
| user_id |       | vehicle_id |    | user_id | vehicle_id |
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+
|       1 |       |          1 |    |       1 |          1 |
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+
```

---

Since you don't want that, you can just remove the `@JoinTable` like so:

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    /* ... */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
}

@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne
    private UserDetails user;
}
```

```
USER_DETAILS      VEHICLE       
+---------+       +------------+---------+
| user_id |       | vehicle_id | user_id |
+---------+       +------------+---------+
|       1 |       |          1 |       1 |
+---------+       +------------+---------+
```

---

You only need a third table if you want to store additional data for a (UserDetails, Vehicle) tuple, in which case you would create a third class.

```
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    /* ... */

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserVehicle> vehicles;
}

@Entity
public class Vehicle {
    /* ... */
}

@Entity
public class UserVehicle {
    /* ... */

    @ManyToOne
    private UserDetails user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Vehicle vehicle;

    @Basic
    private String someString;
}
```

```
USER_DETAILS      VEHICLE           USER_VEHICLE
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+-------------+
| user_id |       | vehicle_id |    | user_id | vehicle_id | some_string |
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+-------------+
|       1 |       |          1 |    |       1 |          1 |  Hello      |
+---------+       +------------+    +---------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, much appreciated! I changed my code to what you suggested and it works just fine without the additional table that i had created before.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that the column is generated. The side of the Many on a database relation have to save the `FK` value.

Try to remove your `@Join` annotation... Just `@OneToMany`

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify relations in `Vehicle` side and in `User` side use `mapedBy` property